# Vuex store state not updating screen / Vue-Native

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-native

I'm using Vue-Native to build a simple Application with multiple Screens (using Vue Native Router). And I have the situation where I connect to a WebSocket in Screen A which listens for messages and I need these updates to be available in Screen A and Screen B.

So after I had no luck with global variables and prototype properties, I came across Vuex which seems to do exactly what I need.

And indeed it updates the properties across the screens fine but it does not seem to be reactive and update the screen.

store.js:

```
import Vue from "vue-native-core";
import Vuex from "vuex"
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        imageUri: ["", "", "", ""]
    },
    mutations: {
      updateImage (state, data) {
        state.imageUri[data.index] = data.url;
      }
    }
  });
```

ScreenA.vue in script-Tag:

```
import store from "./store.js"

export default {
  [...]
  methods: {
    [...]
    handleMessage: function(message){
      var data = message.data.split("#", 2);
      var value = data[1];
      console.log("New msg");


      if(data[0] == "init"){
        this.connectionMs = Date.now()-value;
        this.connectionStatus = 2;
      }else if(data[0] == "img"){
        var current = this.cImg;
        this.cImg = (this.cImg+1)%4;
        var dataUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+value.substring(2, value.length-1);
        store.commit('updateImage', {index: current, url: dataUrl}); //<- Relevant line
      }
    },
    [...]
  }
}
```

ScreenB.vue:

```
<template>
    <view :style="{marginTop: 40}">
        <image resizeMode="contain" :style="{ width: '100%', height: 200 }" :source="{uri: imageUri[0]}"/>
        <image resizeMode="contain" :style="{ width: '100%', height: 200 , marginTop: -200}" :source="{uri: imageUri[1]}"/>
        <image resizeMode="contain" :style="{ width: '100%', height: 200 , marginTop: -200}" :source="{uri: imageUri[2]}"/>
        <image resizeMode="contain" :style="{ width: '100%', height: 200 , marginTop: -200}" :source="{uri: imageUri[3]}"/>
        <touchable-opacity :on-press="btnPress">
            <text>Press me! {{imageUri[0]}}</text>
        </touchable-opacity>
    </view>
</template>

<script>
import store from "./store.js"

export default {
    props: {
        navigation: {
            type: Object
        }
    },
    computed:{
        imageUri: function(){
            return store.state.imageUri;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        btnPress: function(){
            console.log("ImgUrl0 -> "+this.imageUri[0]);
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

The computed property is updating correctly as soon as the vuex state in the store changes (console.log prints new value) but the rendered data on the screen (Text- & Image-Elements) remains with the old data.

Is there any way to solve this issue? Maybe a completely different approach to sync my dynamic data across screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mutation only update `state.imageUri[data.index]`, it will not change reference of `state.imageUri`. That means `state.imageUri` still point to old reference, and Vue can't not detect this update. It's one of [Vue's gotchas](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection)

One solution is using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` to make a deep copy of `state.imageUri` array

```
 export default new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            imageUri: ["", "", "", ""]
        },
        mutations: {
          updateImage (state, data) {
            state.imageUri[data.index] = data.url;
            state.imageUri = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.imageUri))
          }
        }
      });
```